# C# - Unity crashes with this code - creating Transform array based on GameObject tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, behavior

I'm working in a 3D environment, a house, with 16 rooms. In each room I placed an invisible cube with a tag called "RoomsToScanTag". I'm working with an asset called Behavior Designer, and in my inspector I have given the tagname to look for (in this case "RoomsToScanTag"). With this tagname, I want the robot to go to room1 first, then continue to room2, up to room16.

**This is my code**

```
using UnityEngine;
using BehaviorDesigner.Runtime;
using BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Tasks;

public class MoveTowardsNew : Action
{
    private Transform[] roomsToScanHAHA;
    public string targetTagRooms;
    public Transform targetyo;
    int i = 0;
    int controlNumber = 0;

    public override void OnAwake()
    {
        var targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag (targetTagRooms);
        roomsToScanHAHA = new Transform[targets.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < targets.Length; i++) {
            roomsToScanHAHA [i] = targets [i].transform;
        }
    }

    public override TaskStatus OnUpdate()
    {
        while (controlNumber < roomsToScanHAHA.Length)
        {
            targetyo = roomsToScanHAHA [controlNumber];
            if (Vector3.SqrMagnitude (transform.position - targetyo.position) < 0.5f)
            {
                if (controlNumber < roomsToScanHAHA.Length) {
                    controlNumber++;
                }
                return TaskStatus.Success;
            }
        }
        NavMeshAgent agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
        agent.destination = targetyo.position;
        return TaskStatus.Running;
    }
}
```

**My problem**

Unity crashes... It has something to do with this code, I can't figure it out. Anyone has an idea what is going wrong?

Here is an image of what I'm dealing with:

[image: Example of setup in Behavior Designer]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, Its the `while loop` which is not terminating:

```
    while (controlNumber < roomsToScanHAHA.Length)
    {
        targetyo = roomsToScanHAHA [controlNumber];
        if (Vector3.SqrMagnitude (transform.position - targetyo.position) < 0.5f)
        {
            if (controlNumber < roomsToScanHAHA.Length) {
                controlNumber++;
            }
            return TaskStatus.Success;
        }
    }
```

First run: `controlNumber = 0;`

lets say your first element in array `roomsToScanHAHA` doesn't match the condition : `(Vector3.SqrMagnitude (transform.position - targetyo.position) < 0.5f)`. `controlNumber` wont be incremented and would keep checking the condition for the first element. Which results in infinite loop.

So you can change your code to something like this:

```
    while (controlNumber < roomsToScanHAHA.Length)
    {
        targetyo = roomsToScanHAHA [controlNumber];
        if (Vector3.SqrMagnitude (transform.position - targetyo.position) < 0.5f)
        {
            return TaskStatus.Success;
        }
        controlNumber++;
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. BUT, somehow it's not moving towards the first target.. It moves to another spot in the house (close to Room4 for some reason) and not first Room1. What am I doing wrong? The code is the same, with your suggestions.

Comment: If your first target is not close enough it checks for the next one and so on until it finds the closer one (in this case Room4 I assume). Please accept this answer and create a new question with more details telling what you want to achieve. Its better if you add some screenshots from scene view as well :)